# rangeFilter adding unwanted columns ng2-google-charts

Tags: angular5, google-visualization

I'm experiencing some unwanted behavior with ng2-google-charts. I'm able to add moving averages dynamically, VWAP, RSI, and other features fine. I'm also able to access the ChartWrapper using @ViewChild(). However, when using the rangeFilter, it's adding the moving averages from the ComboChart to the rangeFilter, which looks ridiculous. It's also forcing me to add all the columns from the dataTable, or it simply throws an error telling me the columns are missing. All I want to display are the date ranges. Is there any way to do this with the ComboChart? I checked the document and it states that I should be able to specify this in the view of the ChartWrapper with the columns attribute. However, that does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance guys.

```
     const rangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
        containerId: 'cchart',
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            ui: {
                chartOptions: {
                    chartArea: {
                        width: '90%',
                        backgroundColor: '#e5e5e5'
                    }
                },
                minRangeSize: 60000,
                snapToData: true
            }
        },
        view: {
            columns: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
        },
        state: {
            range: {
                start: startDate,
                end: endDate
            }
        }
    });

    if (document.getElementById('cchart')) {
        const dash = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard1'));
        const googleChartWrapper = this.schart.wrapper;
        dash.bind([rangeFilter], [googleChartWrapper]);
        dash.draw(data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work by setting the series in the ChartRangeFilter as shown below.

```
getDateRangeFilter(cid: string, startDate: Date, endDate: Date): any {
    return new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
        controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
        containerId: cid,
        options: {
            filterColumnIndex: 0,
            ui: {
                chartOptions: {
                    background: '#e5e5e5',
                    chartArea: {
                        backgroundColor: '#e5e5e5',
                        width: '98%',
                    },
                    series: {
                        0: { type: 'line', color: 'transparent' },
                        1: { type: 'line', color: 'transparent' },
                        2: { type: 'line', color: 'transparent'  },
                        3: { type: 'line', color: 'transparent' },
                        4: { type: 'line', color: 'transparent' },
                        5: { type: 'line', color: 'transparent' }
                    }

                },
                snapToData: true,
                hAxis: {
                    minValue: startDate,
                    maxValue: endDate
                  }
            }
        },
        view: [0],
        state: {
            range: {
                start: startDate,
                end: endDate
            }
        }
    });
}
```

It's also worth noting that if you're utilizing a ComboChart with candlesticks and you navigate from days to minutes, then your dates need to set using the following:

```
processMinuteHeikenAshiChart(target, haLow, haOpen, haClose, haHigh, date, mvg, mvgx, vwap): any[] {
    const arrData = [];
    //include minutes and seconds
    const ndate = new Date(Date.UTC(date.getYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), 0, 0));
    arrData.push(ndate);
    arrData.push(haLow);
    arrData.push(haOpen);
    arrData.push(haClose);
    arrData.push(haHigh);

    switch (target) {
        case 'short':
            if (this.securityService.shortChartOptions.value.useSMA1) { arrData.push(mvg); }
            if (this.securityService.shortChartOptions.value.useSMA2) { arrData.push(mvgx); }
            if (this.securityService.shortChartOptions.value.showVWAP) { arrData.push(vwap); }
            break;
        case 'long':
            if (this.securityService.longChartOptions.value.useSMA1) { arrData.push(mvg); }
            if (this.securityService.longChartOptions.value.useSMA2) { arrData.push(mvgx); }
            if (this.securityService.longChartOptions.value.showVWAP) { arrData.push(vwap); }
    }

    return arrData;
}
```